# How to get bluetooth icon on status bar in 5.1.1 version when bluetooth is on?

Tags: iphone, ipad

How to get the bluetooth icon on status bar in iphone 5.1.1 version when the bluetooth is on?

Comment: I think when you on Bluetooth it will appear..

Comment: no its not coming on...it will come only when we are in settings...once we are out of the settings the icon disappears.

Answer (score 0):

It only appears if you are actually using bluetooth(details can be found here: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4982?viewlocale=en_US)
I guess Settings uses bluetooth to discover peripherals, that's why the icon is visible.